# Break a string and print line by line

Tags: php

I have a long string as a single line (its too long) and I want it to break and print as a new line whenever we meet a semi colon `;` and `}` or `{` for example

This is my string:

```
aaaaaaaaaaa;bbbbbbbbbb{ccccccccc;dddddddd;}eeeeeee{fffffff;}
```

I want to print it as below:

```
aaaaaaaaaaa;
bbbbbbbbbb{
ccccccccc;
dddddddd;
}
eeeeeeee{
fffffffffff;
}
```

Even if `;` and `}` meet together I wanna break it down and print in two lines.
For example `jjjjjjjjjjjjj;}` might display as

```
jjjjjjjjjjj;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Add <br/> at every end of your line

Comment: Take a look at the `preg_match()` function. And read a bit about "regular expressions". There are many examples for the usage here on SO.

Comment: i cannot add <br> tags manually ,thats what im asking to do dynamically .need a code coz the string is too long .i can not figure out how to use php functions and match these characters and then break don and print

Comment: Is this about CSS beautification? There are libraries for that. (For example, AFAIK, [csstidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/index.php) is written in PHP.)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) as

```
$str = 'aaaaaaaaaaa;bbbbbbbbbb{ccccccccc;dddddddd;}eeeeeee{fffffff;}';
$res = preg_replace('/(;|{|})/',"$1\n",$str);
print_r($res);
```

**Output :**

```
aaaaaaaaaaa;
bbbbbbbbbb{
ccccccccc;
dddddddd;
}
eeeeeeee{
fffffffffff;
}
```

[**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/lN4wX5/1)

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/424097)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace(/([;\{\}])/, '$1<br/>', $sourceLine)` for HTML output. If outputing to file, change `'$1<br/>'` to `"$1\r\n"`

Comment: OP doesn't want to remove `; } {`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like the below code also :

```
$str = 'aaaaaaaaaaa;bbbbbbbbbb{ccccccccc;dddddddd;}eeeeeee{fffffff;}';
$arr_replace_char = array(';','{','}');
$arr_replace_by = array(';<br>','{<br>','}<br>');
echo str_replace($arr_replace_char,$arr_replace_by,$str);
```